# Substituir texto aleatório entre duas strings conhecidas

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Eu preciso substituir um texto aleatório entre duas strings fixas em um banco de dados criado pelo WordPress.

Banco de dados: "database"
Tabela: "wordpress_posts"
Campo: "post_content"
ID: "6450"

Por exemplo, tenho o texto `<inicio do texto fixo> texto aleatório </fim do texto fixo>`, onde temos "texto aleatório" quero que fique "novo texto", da seguinte maneira:

`<inicio do texto fixo> novo texto </fim do texto fixo>`

Eu havia feito uma pergunta, mas foi fechada pois faltava informação, com base num comentário que deixaram cheguei no código abaixo:

```
UPDATE wordpress_posts
SET post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE(
    post_content, 'texto aleatório', 'novo texto')
WHERE `wordpress_posts`.`ID`='6450';
```

Mas eu não sei onde devo informar as strings que são fixas para mudar justamente o texto que está entre elas.

Comment: Conforme a [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace), o segundo parâmetro da função  `REGEXP_REPLACE` aceita o **padrão** a ser substituído. Ou seja, você pode utilizá-lo para a sua expressão regular.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss seguindo os exemplos deixei o comando da seguinte maneira 'UPDATE wordpress_posts SET `post_content` = REGEXP_REPLACE( `post_content`, '<inicio do texto fixo>(.|\n)*?</fim do texto fixo>', 'novo texto') WHERE `wordpress_posts`.`ID`='6450'' mas não surtia efeito, nada é alterado, vide http://prntscr.com/ogxm7y

Comment: alterei a expressão para (.|\n)*?, pra garantir que não era nada errado com as palavras digitadas, mas também não deu em nada http://prntscr.com/ogxmwt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No exemplo dado, a solução seria esta (lembrando que isso só funciona no **MySQL 8.0+**):

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE(
    post_content, '^<inicio do texto fixo>.+<\/fim do texto fixo>$', '<inicio do texto fixo> novo texto </fim do texto fixo>')
WHERE `wp_posts`.`ID`='6450';
```